# alter weekofyear to sun - sat?

Tags: date, hive, counting

I'm trying to count visitors in my data by week using Hive but my week is to start Sunday, not Monday.
Something like this would work but it gives Mon-Sun

```
SELECT 
Month(timestamp), Weekofyear(timestamp), COUNT (DISTINCT userid) 
FROM Data 
Group By Month, Week
```

Is there a way to perhaps alter the timestamp where this would work? This didn't quite seem to align with my numbers doing it with hard coded dates.

```
SELECT 
Month(timestamp), Weekofyear(SUB_DAY(timestamp,1)), COUNT (DISTINCT userid) 
FROM Data 
Group By Month, Week
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered elsewhere by suyash soni:

Simple Solution

You can simply create your own formula instead of going with pre-defined function for "week of the year" Advantage: you will be able to take any set of 7 days for a week.

In your case since you want the week should start from Sunday-Saturday we will just need the first date of sunday in a year

eg- In 2016, First Sunday is on '2016-01-03' which is 3rd of Jan'16 --assumption considering the timestamp column in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'

```
SELECT
count(distinct UserId), lower(datediff(timestamp,'2016-01-03') / 7) + 1 as week_of_the_year 
FROM table.data 
where timestamp>='2016-01-03'
group by lower(datediff(timestamp,'2016-01-03') / 7) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

for start with sunday put below code

```
SELECT 
Month(timestamp), Week(timestamp), COUNT (DISTINCT userid) 
FROM Data 
Group By Month, Week
```

for start with Monday put this

```
SELECT 
Month(timestamp), Week(timestamp,1), COUNT (DISTINCT userid) 
FROM Data 
Group By Month, Week
```

Comment: Sorry I initially wrote week(), Hive does not appear to have this function, it has weekofyear, which does not have a second value it will accept. Which is why I tried to alter the timestamp, but my numbers aren't matching up. Is their a flaw in that logic?